# Multiple shuffle commands produce the same order when run in a loop

Tags: bash, for-loop

I am trying to shuffle some fasta files using the command `shuffle` from biosquid. I wrote a simple `for loop` because I want to create several random sequences. Here is the code

```
for i in {1..15}; do eval "shuffle -w 10 rs11979110.fasta > "$i"_rs11979110.rand"; done
```

I also have tried

```
for i in {1..15}; do `shuffle -w 10 rs11979110.fasta > "$i"_rs11979110.rand`; done
```

but my 15 random fasta files some exactly the same. However when I ran the command in the console 15 times the output is completely different each time (this is what I expect). Any help it would be very appreciated, I know this is a silly question but I am new in bash scripting

Thanks

Comment: This command produces the same output, 15 files with same fasta files

Comment: The `eval` and backquotes do not belong there.  Also, what OS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `shuffle` more than once per second, you'll need to supply a random number seed using the `--seed` option.

By default, `shuffle` seeds the random number generator with `time(0)` (Note 1) which means that if you run it twice in the same second, it will use the same seed and you'll get the same output.

A simple solution is to use bash's `$RANDOM` variable, which will generate a new value on every invocation. Unfortunately, the values are in a small range, so you might want to use the following:

```
shuffle --seed=$((RANDOM*32768 + RANDOM)) -w 10 ...
```

Also, there is no need for eval or backtics. It's sufficient to do this:

```
for i in {1..15}; do
  shuffle --seed=$((RANDOM*32768 + RANDOM)) -w 10 rs11979110.fasta > "$i"_rs11979110.rand
done
```

#### Notes:

1. If you are reading this answer and are responsible for a command-line tool which needs random numbers, this is precisely why you should not copy-and-paste the classic `srand(time(NULL))` line. Use a real random seed, for example by reading a few bytes from `/dev/random`.

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop is correct and should give the result you expect IMHO. You can use the `--seed` option to make `shuffle` use a different seed at each iteration. And you don't need `eval` neither backquotes:

```
for i in {1..15}; do shuffle -w 10 --seed ${i} rs11979110.fasta > ${i}_rs11979110.rand; done
```

I don't know how `shuffle` generates its seed but it remains the same in the execution of the for loop.